# Unable to instantiate NSFetchedResultController with generic type AnyObject in Swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8

I'm experimenting with CoreData in Swift 3 and have come up against a very bizarre circular compiler error in Xcode 8 beta.

NSFetchedResultsController needs a generic type parameter and AnyObject has worked fine up until now. The compiler throws the error:

```
Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestObject'
```

[image: Screen shot]

To make me extra confused, if you delete the type parameter, XCode then says:

```
Reference to generic type NSFetchedResultsController requires argument in `<...>`
```

and helpfully suggests a fix using `<AnyObject>`....and the cycle repeats.

This looks very much like a bug. Any ideas before I report it?

Comment: Do you want to inherit the class from DataProviderDelegate?

Comment: Also never add images to the question unless it is really necessary. Just share the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you take a look into `NSFetchedResultsController`, you can clearly see that it has a parameter with name `ResultType` which conforms to `NSFetchRequestResult`. So you should pass a `type` which conforms to `NSFetchRequestResult`.

So if you take a look into `NSFetchRequestResult`, you can see that it conforms to `NSObjectProtocol`. Also `NSDictionary`, `NSManagedObject` and `NSManagedObjectID`  conforms to `NSFetchRequestResult`.

```
public protocol NSFetchRequestResult : NSObjectProtocol {
}

extension NSDictionary : NSFetchRequestResult {
}

extension NSManagedObject : NSFetchRequestResult {
}

extension NSManagedObjectID : NSFetchRequestResult {
}
```

So it clear that you should pass a `type` from any of these three `NSDictionary` or `NSManagedObject` or `NSManagedObjectID`.

Create your instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` like this.

```
let resultsController : NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>!
```

or like this

```
 let resultsController : NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObjectID>!
```

or like this

```
let resultsController : NSFetchedResultsController<NSDictionary>!
```

Comment: You're quite right - my original (Swift 2) code did not type parameterise NSFetchedResultController. The type parameter was added by an automated Swift 3 refactor and it appears that it is now a requirement as attempting to create this class without a type param is rejected by the Xcode 8 compiler. I suspect my question wasn't that clear so, although it hasn't really resolved the issue, I've accepted anyway. Any other ideas?

Comment: Replace the ```AnyObject``` with ```NSManagedObject```, that's all you have to do. Forget about all other stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Any entity in your Core Data model maps as a subclass of NSManagedObject generated in your code so they all can be used to replace AnyObject, they all conform indirectly to NSFetchRequestResult protocol. You should see which entity/class is being fetch by your FetchRequest connected to this FetchedResultsController and that's the type you should use there.