# Swift 3: NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift3

Today I converted my old code base to swift 3 and xCode did everything but there are few things that I am not able to understand.

Old swift:

```
private var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController?
```

Swift 3:

```
fileprivate var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<AnyObject>?
```

Now the problem is when I simply write the previous one xCode throw an error `Reference to generic type NSFetchedResultsController requires arguments in <....>`

[image]

and it's turned to `NSFetchedResultsController<AnyObject>?` but still it's showing me an error which I am not able to figure.
[image]

Can anyone please help to understand what exactly it mean? and how to figure out?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517493/nsfetchedresultscontroller-deletecache-in-swift-3 for a similar issue. `NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>`  or `NSFetchedResultsController<YourEntity>` should work.

Comment: May be you are right but still I can't solve and understand it either.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: I tried `NSFetchedResultsController<CIDMPerson>` and it's showing the same error.

Comment: Please update the *question* with your code.

Comment: @MartinR I did the same as you have suggested. First time it was not worked. I just clean the project and it's started working. :)

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38172831
It helped me.